# Transformed colors when painting semi-transparent in p5.js

Tags: colors, html5-canvas, p5.js, alpha

A transformation seems to be applied when painting colors in p5.js with an alpha value lower than 255:

```js
for (const color of [[1,2,3,255],[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,13],[10,20,30,40],[50,100,200,40],[50,100,200,0],[50,100,200,1]]) {
  clear();
  background(color);
  loadPixels();
  print(pixels.slice(0, 4).join(','));
}
```

```
Input/Expected Output   Actual Output (Firefox)
1,2,3,255               1,2,3,255 ✅
1,2,3,4                 0,0,0,4
10,11,12,13             0,0,0,13
10,20,30,40             6,19,25,40
50,100,200,40           51,102,204,40
50,100,200,0            0,0,0,0
50,100,200,1            0,0,255,1
```

The alpha value is preserved, but the RGB information is lost, especially on low alpha values.

This makes visualizations impossible where, for example, 2D shapes are first drawn and then the visibility in certain areas is animated by changing the alpha values.

Can these transformations be turned off or are they predictable in any way?

Update: The behavior is not specific to p5.js:

```js
const ctx = new OffscreenCanvas(1, 1).getContext('2d');
for (const [r,g,b,a] of [[1,2,3,255],[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,13],[10,20,30,40],[50,100,200,40],[50,100,200,0],[50,100,200,1]]) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a/255})`;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
  console.log(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data.join(','));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, the HTML Canvas stores colors in a different way that cannot preserve RGB values when fully transparent. When writing and reading pixel data, conversions take place that are lossy due to the representation by 8-bit numbers.

Take for example this row from the test above:

```
Input/Expected Output   Actual Output
10,20,30,40             6,19,25,40
```

| IN (conventional alpha) | R | G | B | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| values | **10** | **20** | **30** | **40** (= 15.6%) |

Interpretation: When painting, add 15.6% of (10,20,30) to the 15.6% darkened (r,g,b) background.

| Canvas-internal (premultiplied alpha) | R | G | B | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | R | G | B | A |
| calculation | 10 * 0.156 | 20 * 0.156 | 30 * 0.156 | 40 (= 15.6%) |
| values | 1.56 | 3.12 | 4.7 | 40 |
| values (8-bit) | 1 | 3 | 4 | 40 |

Interpretation: When painting, add (1,3,4) to the 15.6% darkened (r,g,b) background.

Premultiplied alpha allows faster painting and supports additive colors, that is, adding color values *without* darkening the background.

| OUT (conventional alpha) | R | G | B | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| calculation | 1 / 0.156 | 3 / 0.156 | 4 / 0.156 | 40 |
| values | 6.41 | 19.23 | 25.64 | 40 |
| values (8-bit) | **6** | **19** | **25** | **40** |

So the results are predictable, but due to the different internal representation, the transformation *cannot* be turned off.

The HTML specification explicitly mentions this in section [4.12.5.1.15 Pixel manipulation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#pixel-manipulation):

> Due to the lossy nature of converting between color spaces and converting to and from premultiplied alpha color values, pixels that have just been set using putImageData(), and are not completely opaque, might be returned to an equivalent getImageData() as different values.

see also [4.12.5.7 Premultiplied alpha and the 2D rendering context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#premultiplied-alpha-and-the-2d-rendering-context)

Answer (score 1):

I could be way off here...but it looks like internally that in the `background` method if `_isErasing` is true then `blendMode` is called. By default this will apply a linear interpolation of colours.

See https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/9cd186349cdb55c5faf28befff9c0d4a390e02ed/src/core/p5.Renderer2D.js#L45

See https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/blendMode

> BLEND - linear interpolation of colours: C = A*factor + B. This is the
> default blending mode.

So, if you set the blend mode to `REPLACE` I think it should work.

> REPLACE - the pixels entirely replace the others and don't utilize
> alpha (transparency) values.

i.e.

```
blendMode(REPLACE);
for (const color of [[1,2,3,255],[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,13],[10,20,30,40],[50,100,200,40],[50,100,200,0],[50,100,200,1]]) {
  clear();
  background(color);
  loadPixels();
  print(pixels.slice(0, 4).join(','));
}
```

Comment: Fair point, `blendMode()` affects the results, but `blendMode(REPLACE)` does *not* turn off the transformation, try here https://editor.p5js.org/. `_isErasing` seems to be irrelevant, as it is only involved when using `erase()`, see https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/erase.

Comment: Bounty awarded for pointing to the cause in the blend mode / compositing.